# how to add Timer in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, timer

how are you guys

I've searched about Timer and how it's working in java

I found this easy way which is making for loop then add this commend

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

this commend will make the loop stop for 1 second

BUT

what I want to do is to make an app that looks like a question game

the contestant will see the question and choose the right answer but the timer should be working in the same time

if I used this way ( `Thread.sleep(1000)` )
every thing in the app will stop until the timer finish

what do I do now !?

Comment: Code please my good man!

Comment: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691339/adding-a-timer-and-displaying-label-text/13691413#13691413), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812205/java-swing-change-text-after-delay/13812311#13812311), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888026/java-clock-isnt-counting-in-swing/13888101#13888101), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678750/java-label-timer-and-saving/14678873#14678873)

Comment: What should the timer do??

Comment: why don't you use one more timer and calculate the total time minus second timer value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that : you can do other things while waiting the specified time to execute  remindTask()

```
public class Reminder {
    Timer timer;

    public Reminder(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000);
        //do other things
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            System.out.format("Time's up!%n");
            timer.cancel(); //Terminate the timer thread
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Reminder(5);
        System.out.format("Task scheduled.%n");
    }
}
```

Comment: copied: http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html

Comment: Assuming that OP is using a GUI framework like Swing, this might not be the best option...