# Java Thread manipulating a file

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to make 2 threads manipulate the same file. The problem is that it only creates the file (Thread1 responsibility) but it doesn't populate the file (which is the Thread2 responsibility). Furthermore it sort hangs without finishing the process with exit code().

**here is the output :**

```
File created: example.txt
Thread 1: File creation finished
```

**Here is the complete code :**

```
import java.io.*;

public class ThreadWithFiles {
    private static final String FILE_PATH = "/Users/myUser/Desktop/example.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object lock = new Object();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
            synchronized (lock) {
                createFile();
                System.out.println("Thread 1: File creation finished");
                lock.notify();
            }
        });

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
            synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                    populateFile();
                    lock.notify();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Start both threads
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        try {

            synchronized (lock) {
                thread2.join();
                lock.wait();
                System.out.println("Main thread: Both actions terminated successfully");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createFile() {
        try {
            File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
            if (file.createNewFile()) {
                String[] words = FILE_PATH.split("/");
                String fileName = words[words.length - 1];
                System.out.println("File created: " + fileName);
            } else {
                System.out.println("File already exists: " + FILE_PATH);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void populateFile() {
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(FILE_PATH, true)) {
            writer.write("Hello, this is some text to populate the file.");
            System.out.println("File populated with text");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

so what's going on here?

Comment: If the tasks have to be ordered it doesn't make sense to use threads.

Comment: yes still, but i am practicing Threads. The task doesn't matter, the implementation does. That's why i need to know what's going wrong, because what i want to master is the use of wait() and notify() to coordinate between threads

Comment: Will the program terminate at all?

Comment: You block the thread, theres'no way to finish it. Threads are running in parallel, but you chosed to IO to a file which is synchronized themselves.

Comment: Are you sure that thread 1 starts its execution before thread 2? Because you don't have anything in place that prevents thread 2 from first acquiring the lock, then failing in its `populateFile` method.

Comment: _Lost notification:_ Thread 2 doesn't get to `lock.wait()` until after Thread 1 has completely finished. It misses seeing the earlier `lock.notify()` in Thread 1. It waits forever--waiting for another notification, but no other notification ever happens.

Comment: P.S., If somebody saw you beating on a trumpet with drumsticks, and they told you that was not how a trumpet is meant to be played, would you say, "yes still, but i am practicing?"

Comment: @tquadrat the program doesn't terminate. it hangs WITHOUT finishing the process with exit code(0).

Comment: @RomanC how in parallel? the lock.wait() on thread2 makes it sleep and wait for the notify from thread1

Comment: @RobSpoor i quote " It misses seeing the earlier lock.notify() in Thread 1. It waits forever--waiting for another notification, but no other notification ever happens." how does it miss the lock.notify() of thread1 while thread1 has already finished its task and created the file (the file is created after executing the code)

Comment: @SolomonSlow i know it does not make any sense to use threads in this simple context but as i said, i wonder why the thread2 doesn't get executed.

PS: in thread2 if i "stupidly" put the method populateFile() BEFORE the lock.wait() - which is against the threads mechanism -  the file gets indeed populated with the text, but again this is stupid and not thread safe.

Comment: You should try to use a debugger to debug the execution and see what exactly is being executed.

Comment: @1heone Parallel is when both threads are running simultaneously. It is not like yours theads that blocking each other. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16873592/573032) showcade example threads are started running when you press a button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said by Solomon Slow, if thread 1 calls `notify()` before thread 2 calls `wait()`, no notification will come. This is one of the reasons why this form of locking is sometimes difficult to get right.

Java 5.0 added a lot of classes to help with this in the `java.util.concurrent.*` packages. One that can be really useful here is `CountDownLatch`:

```java
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
    createFile();
    System.out.println("Thread 1: File creation finished");
    latch.countDown();
});

Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        latch.await();
        populateFile();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});

// Start both threads
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
```

You're now telling thread 2 to wait until someone (thread 1) has given the go-ahead. It does impose more ordering, but that's exactly what you need here.

Comment: yes this did work thanks. and for the main thread, i want that the statement inside the main thread gets executed the last one. i guess i can't use ```latch.await();``` in the main thread as well... or can i?

Comment: @1heone in that case you need a second `CountDownLatch`. Thread 2 calls its `countDown()` method in a `finally` block - that way it will get triggered even if the `populateFile` throws an exception. But `thread2.join()` will still work, because that will block until thread 2 ends, which is after the `populateFile` method ends as well.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote in a comment,

> *Lost notification:* Thread 2 doesn't get to `lock.wait()` until after Thread 1 has completely finished. It misses seeing the earlier `lock.notify()` in Thread 1. It waits forever--waiting for another notification, but no other notification ever happens.

You responded,

> how does it miss the `lock.notify()` of thread1 while thread1 has already finished its task

`lock.notify()` will wake a thread that is already waiting for the notification, but it does *nothing at all* if no other thread is waiting. The `lock` does not remember that it was notfied. If `thread1` starts first, then it locks the `lock`, and `thread2` gets stuck trying to enter the `synchronized(lock)` block until `thread1` has completely finished.

`thread2` is still stuck trying to enter the synchronized block when thread1 calls `notify`. The `notify()` call then does absolutely nothing--has no effect whatsoever--because no other thread is waiting for it at that moment.

Finally, after `thread1` is completely finished, and it releases the lock, ***then*** `thread2` is able to get in to its `synchronized(lock)` block and call `lock.wait()`. But too late! `thread1` is done and gone. No second notification will ever happen, and `thread2` waits forever. The program never ends.

Comment: I understand what are you trying to explain and i agree 100%. But as you see in my code thread2 is indeed waiting for thread1 to complete and releases the lock.

Comment: @1heone, I see that thread2 cannot _begin_ to `wait()` until after it enters the synchronized block, and if thread1 starts first, then thread2 cannot enter the synchronized block until after thread1 already has given the notification.

Comment: In short: thread 1 finishes before thread 2 calls `lock.wait()`; nothing will call `lock.notify()` anymore to wake up thread 2, and it's deadlocked.

Comment: yes indeed.....