# How to have timing in a java game?

Tags: java, swing, delay

I have a game that includes timing as the game progresses, i mean you play the game and time ticks as you play, and when its done it stops the game. But i can't run two threads of code at once... is there any way i could fix this?

here is my timers code:

```
public class Time {
private static String gl;
private static int gli;
public static int weeks = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    startdays();
}
public static void startdays() throws InterruptedException {
    gl = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many weeks? do you want the game to to on for?\nPlease type numbers, Or game will crash.\nEach week is 10 seconds long.");
    gli = Integer.parseInt(gl);
    gli++;

    for (int i = 0; i < gli; i++) {         
        if(weeks < gli){
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            weeks++;
        }else if(weeks == gli){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Uh oh, Your time in office is up. You died of an infectuous disease.");                
        }
    }
}
}
```

In another class I call the method like so

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, compname);
    Time time = new Time();
    time.startdays();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Im still here");
```

So is there any way to have the timer and the game going at the same time?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Swing, you are already running multiple threads, as Swing runs in it's own thread.

Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

In particular, `javax.swing.Timer` is most likely the most useful option to you

**Updated**

Possible examples

- [Java Label Timer and Saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678750/java-label-timer-and-saving/14678873#14678873)
- [Java clock isn't counting in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888026/java-clock-isnt-counting-in-swing/13888101#13888101)